# Unity3D - Retrieve Firebase message data after user dismisses the notification

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've managed to retrieve the data when the app is in foreground and when the app is in the background and the user tap the notification. The problem happens when the user dismiss the notification, the `FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived` callback never got called.

Is there a way to retrieve/retain the notification data when the user dismissed the Firebase notification?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this behaviour is specific to messages that contains both notification and data payload. If you want to receive the data packet no matter what, send it as pure data package. 
In this case, I simply split the message into two, one containing the notification and the other containing the data, and then send them via the Fcm HTTP endpoint separately.